# MongoDB: How update array of documents using schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var product = {
    itemId: 12898498487,
    content: "Content"
};

MyColletion.update({ 'itemId': product.itemId }, product, { upsert: true });
```

This works.
How can i update array of objects ? Insert products works fine...

**EDIT**

```
insertProducts(products: IProduct[]) {
    var resolver = Promise.defer();

    Product.collection.insert(products)
        .then(() => {
            resolver.resolve());
        });

    return resolver.promise;
}
```

Then i want to update inserted documents with new data. How? If i try change **insert** method to **update** nothing will happend.

Comment: You gave an example of something trivially working, but could you give an example of exactly what you want to achieve with arrays?

Comment: At first. I have array of objects. Throught schema.collection insert these documents to db. Then i want to do the same operation width update method. But it doesnt work.

Comment: Could you give an example document with the array and what you'd like to update with the query?

Comment: I edited question.

Comment: Since you (most likely) want separate fields/values updated per document, I suspect you need to use [`bulk`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/) or just loop and generate an update per document.

Comment: No. I want to update all fields in document. In Schema field "itemId" is unique. If i used loop nothing happened.